# VNC Config Window only when autostarting VNCServer Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, cron, vnc, autostart

[image]I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed with TigerVNC and I use the following settings in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
export DESKTOP_SESSION=/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu
```

For autostarting the VNC server, I use `crontab -e` and start it like that: `@reboot /usr/bin/vncserver :2`.

The problem is that I only get a black screen with the VNC config window, but if I enter the same command manually it works without any issues and I get my gnome desktop as directly on the machine.

Comment: Comment out the lines in xstartup that start with '[' char. And make sure to have vncserver.users file in /etc/tigervnc/ dir.

Comment: I commented the '[' lines. I do not have the users file. Should I just create it? What would be the content?

Comment: username:2 . Your username then display number you use for vnc

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything either